# Cannot find module - user profile directory contains non-ASCII character ø

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, yarnpkg

I'm trying to build a react package in a mono repo. When trying to build the React package, it throws `Cannot find module` error as seen bellow. Notice that the path it tries to look up has been transformed, replacing the `ø` character in my user directory name with `├╕` resulting in the path: `... Users\LarsM├╕ster\ ...`, which is clearly wrong.

I have built the project many times for several months now, and this is the first time I encounter this error.

```
yarn run v1.22.19
warning package.json: No license field
$ yarn run clean && npm run compile && rollup -c
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:959
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\LarsM├╕ster\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\bin\yarn.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:956:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:804:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
error Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
Arguments: C:\Users\LarsMøster\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\yarn\lib\cli.js run build
Directory: ...\packages\react
Output:
```

I have tried to reinstall node.js, as well as removing the yarn lock and node modules, and reinstalling the dependencies. Building the other packages of the monorepo succeeds, it is only the react package that encounters this issue.

It is possible that I could either rename the user directory (which seems very risky) or move the node modules somewhere else, but I don't know the implications of doing either of these tings, so any input on that would be appreciated.